# What is the Taylor Expansion of $x^2$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

What is the Taylor Expansion of the expression $x^2$ ?

Is it possible to express this as a general expression evaluated at any point?

**Edit** I have been asked to explain why this question is different from [Taylor series of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22390/taylor-series-of-a-polynomial)

Personally, the difference for me is that I am unable to understand the linked question which I believe is significantly more complex than my own!

Comment: Around what point do you want to expand?

Comment: Hint: It is finite

Comment: Around $x=0$, that would be $x^2$...

Comment: It may be that I am misunderstanding something, but is it possible to create a general expression for producing Taylor Expansion for $x^2$?

Comment: The general formula is still the same as always, but all the terms will vanish (equal to 0) except $x^2$.

Comment: You can do this one by algebra: if $a$ is a fixed point then $$x^2  = a^2 + 2a(x-a) + (x-a)^2$$ for all $x$.

Comment: Around $0$: itself. Around another point: your have an algorithm to expand any polynomial by powers of $x-a$ for any $a$, by successive divisions, similar to the algorithm to convert the decimal expansion if an integer into its axpansion in any base.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taylor series of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22390/taylor-series-of-a-polynomial)

Comment: Thanks Umberto P.!  That is what I had written down, which gives me some confidence that I am beginning to understand Taylor Expansions.  If you put this as an answer I will accept..

Comment: Why so many down votes?  I think it's pretty off-putting for someone like me who is trying to teach themselves Maths to have their questions down voted so harshly without any explaination!

Answer (score 3):

Example: expansion of $x^3+5x$ in powers of $x-2$ by the method of *successive divisions*:

- $x^3+5x=(x^2+2x+5)(x-2)+\color{red}{10}$;
- $x^2+2x+5=(x+4)(x-2)+\color{red}{13}$;
- $x+4=\color{red}{1}\cdot(x-2)+\color{red}{6}$
  Then the expansion is:
  $$x^3+5x=\color{red}{1}\cdot(x-2)^3+\color{red}{6}(x-2)^2+\color{red}{13}(x-2)+\color{red}{10}.$$